# How to bind jQuery Datepicker after Ajax refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, jquery-events

I've got a jQuery datepicker that is working great for me, except when I fresh the content via ajax, I lose the datepicker. From what I can tell I should be using jQuery `on()` to bind it to the input, but I can't seem to find the right event to bind it to.

Works the first time, but not on subsequent refreshes:

```
$("[id^=startPicker]").datetimepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/img/calendar_icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
        stepMinute: 1,
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {

            var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); //Date object

            $.ajax({
                url: "/url",
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    value: selectedDate.toDateString() + ' ' + selectedDate.toTimeString()
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loading").fadeIn();
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loading").fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Doesn't bind first time or on subsequent refreshes:

```
$('#content').on('ready', "[id^=startPicker]", function () {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/img/calendar_icon.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            stepMinute: 1,
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
    
                var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); //Date object
    
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/url",
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        value: selectedDate.toDateString() + ' ' + selectedDate.toTimeString()
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#loading").fadeIn();
                    },
                    success: function (data, textStatus) {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("#loading").fadeOut();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You cannot delegate this plugin with the `.on()` event out of the box. You will need to re-instantiate the plugin on the elements in the `.success()` callback.

Comment: ready event is used only on document even you can bind it to any other elements. But using .on() syntax, this will not be fired after ready event is done, unlike using alias $().ready()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery `.on()` function is for deferred event handling, but it doesn't work for plugin initialization.

It works for events because the DOM model propagates events from DOM elements to their parent elements, all the way to the top.  So when you click on a link, you're also clicking on whatever contains that link (a `div` for example), whatever contains that container, and so on all the way up to the `body` tag and eventually the `document` itself.  `.on()` takes advantage of this by binding to the click event of a common parent element instead of the dynamic child elements, so child elements can be added/removed without losing the event handler on the parent.

Plugin initialization doesn't work this way, though.  In order to initialize a plugin on a target element, it *must* be done on the element itself which means the element needs to be in the DOM at the time.  Thus, when you add new elements dynamically, you need to target those new elements and initialize the plugin on them.  So your `success` function from the AJAX call would need to do that.

Note that since your AJAX call is itself *inside* of your initialization, you're going to need to split some of these out into separate functions for re-use.  Otherwise this re-initialization would nest inside itself indefinitely.

Maybe something like this:

```
var datePickerClose = function (dateText, inst) {

    var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); //Date object

    $.ajax({
        url: "/url",
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            value: selectedDate.toDateString() + ' ' + selectedDate.toTimeString()
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#loading").fadeIn();
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $("#content").html(data);
            $("#content").find("[id^=startPicker]").each(function () {
                bindDatePicker(this);
            });
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#loading").fadeOut();
        }
    });
};

var bindDatePicker = function(element) {
    $(element).datetimepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/img/calendar_icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
        stepMinute: 1,
        onClose: datePickerClose
    });
};

$("[id^=startPicker]").each(function() {
    bindDatePicker(this);
});
```

This is, of course, free-hand untested code just to demonstrate the concept.  It may require a little tweaking, and there may be a more elegant way to accomplish the same logic.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I'm almost there!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I'm almost there!

`$("[id^=startPicker]").each(function() {
    bindDatePicker(this);
});`

works perfectly for binding on page load, but:

`$("#content").find("[id^=startPicker]").each(function () {
                bindDatePicker(this);
            });`
doesn't seem to be executing, at least according to the firefox ddebugger. I've also tried calling it on success from other ajax functions and getting the same thing.

Comment: @richj: Is the AJAX call successfully returning?  If the `success` handler is invoked then it should be reaching that line of code.

Comment: It appears that even though the function works, i.e. the date is updated and the html for the page is returned and there are no errors, the success handler is not firing. I've even tried adding a simple alert to the success to test it and no result. How do I verify the result of the ajax call? Firefox says: 'GET http://url/... 200 OK'

Comment: I moved the binding to the complete handler and it's working, but I assume it's bad form to use the complete handler for that functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You can not delegate plugin, delegation is for event listener only. Use the success callback function and reinitailize datepicker plugin once targeted element is added

```
success: function (data, textStatus) {
    $("#content").html(data).find('[id^=startPicker]').datepicker({...});
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similiar problem: After an ajax page reload I can't set new datepicker with *$(element).datepicker()*. Because Datepicker only does once a clean initialization, I just set directly after ajax success:

```
$.datepicker.initialized = false;
```

Now the next *$(element).datepicker()* will cause a fresh initialization. This affects all datepicker on the side, so you may have reset datpicker outside the ajax-container.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the simplest way I have found to do this is by simply putting the bind code within the success function like so: `ELEMENT.datepicker();`.

Eg: `$('.datepicker').datepicker();`

Full code:

```
$('#loaddetails').on('click',function(){
                //Run ajax fetch here
                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "yourlink",
                       data: $('form').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                       dataType: 'json',
                       beforeSend: function () {
                         console.log('Form serialised');
                         $('#status').html('<img src="../img/spinner.gif" width="16" height="16">');
                         },
                       success: function(data)
                       {
                        $('#status').html(data);
                        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
                          },
                          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                          }
                     });
                console.log("All ok");
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with datetimepicker then use this:
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker("destroy"); statement before ajax call, to remove existing instance of datetimepicker.
It will render a new datetimepicker instance that works fine without refreshing or reloading the window.
See the full code:

```
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker("destroy"); // add this line before ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0], 
                format: 'L',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```